# getView() of ArrayAdapter not getting called

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I am doing Flickr integration and using Json parsing..I am able to fetch data  but its not displaying because getView() method of adapter is not getting called..However constructor of adapter class is called as i checked using Toast messages..I have no clue why getView() is not getting called...I have checked other questions with almost similar issue but unable to find solution that solves my problem

```
public class FlickrImagesList extends Fragment
{
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    ArrayList<Flickr> flickrList;

    private static final String photo = "photo";
   private static final String id = "id";
    private static final String owner = "owner";
    private static final String secret = "secret";
    private static final String server = "server";
    private static final String farm = "farm";
    private static final String title = "title";
    private static final String ispublic = "ispublic";
    private static final String isfriend = "isfriendt";
    private static final String isfamily = "isfamily";

ImageLoader imageLoader;
  FlickrListAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flickr_main_list, container, false);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
  //      imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
//        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(myContext));
        rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        flickrList= new ArrayList<Flickr>();
            new JSONAsyncTask().execute("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=xyz&format=json&group_id=2058557@N24&nojsoncallback=1");
        ListView listview = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listflickr);
      adapter = new FlickrListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.flickr_list_single,flickrList);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;
    }
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            try
            {


                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Log.e("status","status");
                if (status == 200) {
                    Log.e("status2","status2");
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    entity.consumeContent();
                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("photos");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        Log.e("status3","status3");
                        JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            JSONObject ph = c.getJSONObject(photo);

                        Flickr actor = new Flickr();
                        if(ph.has(id)) {
                            actor.setId(ph.getString(id));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(owner)) {
                            actor.setOwner(ph.getString(owner));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(secret))
                        {
                            actor.setSecret(ph.getString(secret));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(server)) {
                            actor.setServer(ph.getString(server));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(farm)) {
                            actor.setFarm(ph.getString(farm));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(title)) {
                            actor.setTitle(ph.getString(title));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(ispublic)) {
                            actor.setIspublic(ph.getString(ispublic));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(isfriend)) {
                            actor.setIsfriend(ph.getString(isfriend));
                        }
                        if(ph.has(isfamily)) {
                            actor.setIsfamily(ph.getString(isfamily));
                        }
                        Log.e("actor.getServer()", actor.getServer());
 flickrList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            }
            catch (ParseException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("exception", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
        {

            dialog.cancel();
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

}
```

FlickrListAdapter

```
public class FlickrListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flickr> {
    ArrayList<Flickr> flickrList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;
    DisplayImageOptions options;


    public FlickrListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Flickr> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        Toast.makeText(context,"FlickrListAdapter",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        flickrList = objects;
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.color.transparent)
                .showImageOnFail(android.R.color.transparent)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"getView",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.flickr_image);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_icon);


        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("https://farm" + flickrList.get(position).getFarm() + ".staticflickr.com/" + flickrList.get(position).getServer() + "/"
                + flickrList.get(position).getId() + "_" + flickrList.get(position).getSecret() + ".jpg",holder.imageview, options);


    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView textview;
        public TextView textview2;
    }


}
```

If i add

```
@Override
    public int getCount () {
        return 1;
    }
```

then app crashes showing error on ImageLoader

```
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Comment: did you check size of flickrList ? if it is 0, it is too obvious getView will not be called

Comment: @Adem i think tht is the reason why getView() is not called here..but why the size of list is 0?check my FlickrImagesList class..i am adding content to list through flickrList.add(actor); and i checked through logcat that content is being fetched in json parsing..

Comment: @summea check my doInBackground() method..i am adding content to list through flickrList.add(actor); and i checked through logcat that content is being fetched in json parsing.

Comment: @user3753273 can you try     public int getCount () {
        return flickrList.size() ;
    }     it seems this adapter should support automatically, but to be sure you could try this

Comment: @summea I have put full code of FlickrImagesList.java class in the question..u can see i am doing JSON parsing in doInBackground() method inside AsyncTask

Comment: @summea I checked through it..list size is 0..but unable to find out why data is not added in list

Comment: i am adding content to list through flickrList.add(actor); and i checked through logcat that content is being fetched in json parsing..also i have put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside onPostExecute() then why content is not added in list.why my listview size is still 0?

Comment: @summea  maybe issue is because its bot going inside for loop of doInBackground() method..is there any problem in the statement - JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("photos")

Comment: @Adem maybe issue is because its bot going inside for loop of doInBackground() method..is there any problem in the statement - JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("photos")

Comment: @summea check out..i am using this url.. https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=a36e27e73ef52f4e14cfe25b2c1e42bd&format=json&group_id=2058557@N24&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: @Adem check out..i am using this url.. https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=a36e27e73ef52f4e14cfe25b2c1e42bd&format=json&group_id=2058557@N24&nojsoncallback=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter´s `getView()` is not called because the list `flickrList` that you get from your `JSONAsyncTask()` is empty.

in fact you are getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

According  to your .json response
**http://www.mocky.io/v2/548b349c9739deb61372aecf**

The problem is your parser, this will fix your problem:

```
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONObject jb = jsono.getJSONObject("photos");
                JSONArray jarray = jb.getJSONArray("photo");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    Log.e("status3","status3");
                    JSONObject ph = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Flickr actor = new Flickr();
```

Comment: check my doInBackground() method..i am adding content to list through flickrList.add(actor); and i checked through logcat that content is being fetched in json parsing..also i have put     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside onPostExecute() then why content is not added in list.why my listview size is still 0?

Comment: hey you need an API KEY, because im getting: {"stat":"fail","code":100,"message":"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"}  , if you are not setting the API KEY you will get 0 results.

Comment: i am setting api key..maybe issue is because its bot going inside for loop of doInBackground() method..is there any problem in the statement -    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("photos");

Comment: yeah i have used api key

Comment: check out..i am using this url.. https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?method=flickr.groups.pools.getPhotos&api_key=a36e27e73ef52f4e14cfe25b2c1e42bd&format=json&group_id=2058557@N24&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: thank you thats what i wanted, give me a moment to see what happen, and please avoid this:    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); , for that´s what we to use the asynctasks :P

Comment: yes the problem was the parser, i have posted here the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was where I am creating JSONObject thats why size of list is zero since jarray was zero..I resolved it by changing to..

```
 JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                        JSONObject c = jsono.getJSONObject(photos);
                        JSONArray jarray = c.getJSONArray(photo);

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    Log.e("status3","status3");
                    JSONObject ph = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Flickr actor = new Flickr();
```

Comment: @Jorgesys is there any difference in the code u posted and wht i posted?

Comment: post your code again! (Im sorry i have replaced the original)

Comment: my code is same wht i have posted in this answer and tht solved my problem

Comment: is exactly the same!, there is no difference! you are using the variables photos and photo instead of the strings directly, that is better.